# Is union queries act as one transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, union

Suppose, i have such query:

```
SELECT id1 AS id, SUM(`value`), 'in' AS `type` FROM transaction WHERE id1 = 3434
UNION
SELECT id2 AS id, SUM(`value`), 'out' AS `type` FROM transaction WHERE id2 = 4568
```

Does query #2 see the same data as it was when query #1 started ?

Comment: Why are you using a `union` for this query?  It is unnecessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why not?

Comment: I think, there is no #2nd Query. It is a single query.

Comment: here Id1 and id2 are different...?

Then select id1,id2,sum('value') from transaction where id1=3434 and id2=3434

Comment: @JithinShaji you right, i used wrong term "query" for reffering to part of single SQL query (don`t know what word would be more appropriate)

Comment: @koushikveldanda my bad, id1 and id2 in real query are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your example is a *single* query, not two queries.  The query, as written, will scan the source data twice, but it is still one query.

The property that you are looking for is the "isolation" property of ACID.  You can learn more about ACID [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and on MySQL's support [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-acid.html).

Most databases, including MySQL, are ACID-compliant with the right configuration parameters.  However, this is controlled by various parameters, particularly the isolation level of individual transaction.  Because full ACID compliance can require a lot of overhead (for instance, preventing a `UPDATE` from running at all once a `SELECT` query has started on the same table), some of the conditions are sometimes relaxed.

ACID-compliance depends on the parameters for your particular configuration and on your storage engine.  However, MySQL can and does support isolation if you need it.

Also note that the `UNION` has little to do with isolation, except that it requires scanning the data twice which would make a lack of isolation more obvious.